# Using Android futures to move heavy computation to background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask, future

I have a function that runs on the Android main thread (UI thread):

```
fun someFunc() {

  ...
  doSomething1()
  doSomething2()
  doSomething3()
  ...
}
```

`doSomething2` is a heavy computation that causes main thread to be blocked, causing an ANR on Android.

I want to run doSomething2() asynchronously in a background thread using Android Futures and after that completes, resume processing from `doSomething3` in main thread again.
I also want to make sure is not blocked while `doSomething2` runs on the background thread (to resolve the ANR).

I'm planning to do something like

```
   ...
   doSomething1()
   Future f = <trigger doSomething2 to run on BG thread and return future>
   f.get()
   doSomething3()
   ...
```

The `f.get` makes sure we wait for the result of `doSomething2`, but does it free up the main thread while it waits? or will it keep the main thread blocked while it waits?

Comment: It will block the thread in which it has been invoked. So if you invoke `f.get()` in the main thread, main thread execution will be blocked until the future task is complete. If `doSomething2` is really that heavy you must execute it in another thread rather than the main thread. When the process is complete then you can deliver the results to the main thread using an interface ar another similar mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract V get (long timeout, 
            TimeUnit unit)
```

> Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to
> complete, and then retrieves its result, if available.

I read it as it blocks the thread it's running on, thus, waiting. As you can see there's also a timeout param, probably to give flexibility to how long you'd want to freeze the running thread.

After further reading:

> The result can only be retrieved using method get when the computation has completed, blocking if necessary until it is ready.